# Change appropriately legend titles in ggplotly function from R package plotly

Tags: r, ggplot2, plotly

Recently, I was trying through Rstudio and from package `ggplot2`, to create an interactive `pca` plot (regarding some gene expression data) using as final function the `ggplotly` function (from the R package `ggplotly`). In detail, part of my code:

```
mat <- exprs(eset.4) # one expression set for input pca <- prcomp(t(mat), scale=TRUE)
pcvar = pcasdev2/sum(pcasdev2/sum(pcasdev^2)*100
tot <- cbind(pca$x,phenotype_dat) # which renders the variables info
p <- ggplot(tot, aes(PC1,PC2, colour=Disease,shape=Study) p <- p + geom_point(size=3) + xlab(paste0("PC1: ",round(pcvar1,2),"% variance")) + ylab(paste0("PC2: ",round(pcvar[2],2),"% variance"))
ggplotly(p)
```

The only problem is that the legend labels in the output image are not clear-organized and well separated (for instance i would like each title label (i.e. Disease) to go along with its subcategories-levels, such as Cancer-Normal)  !! Is there a way to fix this in the above implementation with `ggplotly` ?

[image]